Is there a way to automatically split a long three columned HTML table into more columns
I have a table that is being generated by PHP queries in MySql
A bit of context:
The queries exist of a search and count for a certain hardware type found in database called "hardware".
The "userdata" database holds all user data including which hardware type they use.
The query plots the hardware type and counts them in the userdata database and plots that number behind the hardware type. This way I know the amound of a certain hardware type being in use. Each itteration then plots the HTML code for the table.
The thing is, the table is a bit too long for my dashboard, and I would like to see it split in more columns.
Currently the table is 3 columns wide, displaying hardware type, the number and a search button.
The output is a bit extensive and it has some formatting so apologies for the cluttering.


<table id="hwcounter" align="left" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="25%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font size="5">
        <font size="5"><b>Hardware Overview</b></font>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left"><b>Hardware Type</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Number at customers</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo t480c
      <td>1</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small> <input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20t480c" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo T490c
      <td>7</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T490c" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo T14g1
      <td>36</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T14g1" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo X13g1 PF
      <td>8</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20X13g1%20PF" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo T14g1_ac
      <td>2</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T14g1_ac" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo P15
      <td>1</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20P15" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo T14g2
      <td>123</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T14g2" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo X13g2 PF
      <td>18</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20X13g2%20PF" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Apple iPad Pro
      <td>17</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Apple%20iPad%20Pro" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo T14g2_ac
      <td>4</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T14g2_ac" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo X13g2 NP
      <td>3</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20X13g2%20NP" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo T14g3_ac
      <td>7</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T14g3_ac" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo X13g3 PF
      <td>22</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20X13g3%20PF" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo T14g3
      <td>34</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20T14g3" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>ThinkCentre M90
      <td>1</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=ThinkCentre%20M90" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo X13g4
      <td>8</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20X13g4" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>Lenovo X13g3
      <td>1</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20X13g3" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>Lenovo P16g1
      <td>1</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=Lenovo%20P16g1" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>HP ZBOOK G11
      <td>1</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=HP%20ZBOOK%20G11" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>HP x360 G10 cp
      <td>2</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=HP%20x360%20G10%20cp" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td>HP 840 G10
      <td>4</td>
      <td style="width:15px" align="left"><small><input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=HP%20840%20G10" value="View List" /></small></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <br />
  <hr>
</table>



Is there a way to automatically "break" of the table at row 10 (e.g.) and move the rest into a next group of columns? etc etc?
I looked at CSS Grid etc, but it doesn't seem to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/6pnrygjp/ With span came closest, but I cannot use 3 columns. It mixes everything up

Just as an aside to the issue, you should fix the quality of the HTML. Your table is invalid because it has additional unnecessary </tr> tags, it also contains <hr> and<br> which should not be there, and the input elements should not be witihn small tags. Finally, font tags and the bgcolor attribute were deprecated almost 20 years ago, use CSS instead. Similarly, don't use onclick attributes - bind your event handlers in JS, not HTML - however even even then you're using button element to redirect the page with JS, just use an a element and remove the need for JS at all

With regard to the issue, can you not amend the PHP to generate the table to output 6 columns? 2 type/number pairs at a time? Using JS for this is a bandaid fix at best

You could either generate multiple tables, and have them show next to each other using display: inline-table or something like that. Or, if you want it all in one table - then you'd need to determine how many records you have to show upfront, and then put the data into the correct columns into the correct row to begin with. (I.e., your data from record #1 needs to go into cells 1, 2 and 3 of the first row, and then you need to continue with creating cells 4, 5, and 6 with the data from the 11th record, before you actually close that row with a </tr> again ...

Hi Rory. I am not an expert as you can see :) I will fix the HTML coding. Thanks for your tips
How can I get 2 results in one iteration to be able to create 6 columns?
This is the PHP code
// retrieve all hardware types
$qhwtype="select hardware_type from hardware";
$rhwtype=mysqli_query($dbc,$qhwtype);

// plot the table
while ($hwrow = mysqli_fetch_row($rhwtype)){
$bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee'); // Switch the background color.
echo '';
foreach ($hwrow as $item) {
// plotting known hardware types
echo '' . htmlspecialchars($item) . '';
$qhwcount="select * from userdata where current_hardware='$item'";

// counting the amount of each hardware type amongst users
$rhwcount=mysqli_query($dbc,$qhwcount);
echo mysqli_num_rows($rhwcount) . '
<input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick=window.location.href="search_client.php?keyname=' .$hwsearchstring = str_replace(' ','%20', $item) . '" value="View List" />';
}
echo '';

Yes ... use the often-overlooked columns property.


.d1 {
  columns: 4;
}
<div class="d1">
<table>
<tr><td>R1 C1</td><td>R1 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R2 C1</td><td>R2 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R3 C1</td><td>R3 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R4 C1</td><td>R4 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R5 C1</td><td>R5 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R6 C1</td><td>R6 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R7 C1</td><td>R7 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R8 C1</td><td>R8 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R9 C1</td><td>R9 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R10 C1</td><td>R10 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R11 C1</td><td>R11 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R12 C1</td><td>R12 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R13 C1</td><td>R13 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R14 C1</td><td>R14 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R15 C1</td><td>R15 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R16 C1</td><td>R16 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R17 C1</td><td>R17 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R18 C1</td><td>R18 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R19 C1</td><td>R19 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R20 C1</td><td>R20 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R21 C1</td><td>R21 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R22 C1</td><td>R22 C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>R23 C1</td><td>R23 C2</td></tr>
</table>
</div>




This is very cool! Only thing I am not sure how to do or if it is possible is to put the table header above each column. Is that possible at all?

Not with this method, no.

OK. Thank you so much! This helps a lot

I am using Firefox, but I didn't see the table divided into 4 columns, is this normal?

You can use text shadow to put the column headings in, if you know the width to displace them by.
